# How can I make a pointy arrow with a div in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How can I make a pointy arrow in CSS? Not just a triangle but one with a stem, like a traditional arrow that would be fired from a bow?

I'm trying to do it by creating a div container, containing two containers, left and right. The right will contain the triangle, and the left will contain three divs, the centre of which will be colored to create the stem.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    <div class='arrowblock'>
        <div class='arrowright'></div>
        <div class='rectcontainer'>
            <div class='rect'></div>
            <div class='rect' style='background-color:green'>
            </div><div class='rect'>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectcontainer {
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
}

.arrowblock {
    width:130px;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
}
.arrowright {
float:right;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid green;
}
.rect {
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: Sometimes, using a good ol' image is ok.

Comment: If you put in Google: "CSS arrow", you'll find a lot of articles that explain how you can achieve this.

Comment: I've updated this question with the code which I believed could be improved upon.

Comment: @leoMestizo, if you Google "CSS arrow" you get a lot of articles showing you how to make a triangle using CSS. My question specifically states that I'm not looking for this, that I'm looking for one with a stem too. Please find me the Google search result that gives me that information if it's that easy.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is an arrow with pure **CSS**. Supported by *all* browsers. It took me less than a minute to make..

[image]

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqcFp/)

```css
.arrow {
  width: 120px;
}

.line {
  margin-top: 14px;
  width: 90px;
  background: blue;
  height: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.point {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 30px solid blue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="point"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great, so much better than attempt. I was looking for code which would change the arrow size and color programatically so I've updated your code here http://jsfiddle.net/fqcFp/2/

Comment: You can get rid of the .line/.point classes and elements and just use ::before and ::after pseudo-elements instead.

Comment: Maybe you can using these lines for change direction, CSS:
.arrow-left-direction .line { float: right; }
.arrow-left-direction .point { border-right: 30px solid blue; border-left: none; float: left; } in HTML: <div class="arrow arrow-left-direction"> here fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6ryd8c7k/9/

Answer (score 9):

To build on @josh-crozier's answer, you can eliminate a lot of the HTML by using pseudo-elements instead:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aov455y/1)

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    position:relative;
    width:120px;
    margin:50px auto;
    height:0;
    border-bottom:10px solid blue;
}

.arrow::after { 
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: -10px;
    top: -15px;
}
```

To add an arrow at the start of the line using the ::before element is trivial also: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aov455y/)

Answer (score 5):

How about just using a html entity or unicode symbol for your arrow:

```
<div>&#8594;</div>

<div title="U+21A3: RIGHTWARDS ARROW WITH TAIL">↣</div>

div{
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/52yjK/1/)**

There are more to choose from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aUnicode_chart_Arrows)

Comment: Nice idea, but you have no control over the size of the arrowhead this way.

Answer (score 3):

I've created this, which you can use for an arrow that points to the right.

In the script are two variables, widthofarrow and colorofarrow. By changing these you can create an arrow of any size or color.

http://jsfiddle.net/FKekh/3/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="main"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.rectcontainer {
    height:30px;
}

.arrowblock {

}
.arrowright {
float:right;
    }
.rect {
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
widthofarrow=130;
colorofarrow="#345678";

$("#main").append("<div class='arrowblock'><div class='arrowright'></div><div class='rectcontainer'><div class='rect'></div><div class='rect' style='background-color:" + colorofarrow + "'></div><div class='rect'></div></div></div>");


$('.arrowblock').css('width', widthofarrow + 'px');
$('.rectcontainer').css('width', (widthofarrow - (30)) + 'px');    
$('.arrowright').css('border-top', (15) + 'px solid transparent');
$('.arrowright').css('border-bottom', (15) + 'px solid transparent');
$('.arrowright').css('border-left', (widthofarrow/4.333333333333333) + 'px solid ' + colorofarrow);
```

EDIT

I've updated JoshC's great code so it can be used to create arrows of different sizes and colors.

http://jsfiddle.net/fqcFp/2/

Answer (score 1):

Taking Josh's answer a bit further I have made an example that adjusts width based on the container keeping it pure CSS. Thanks @Josh  for the starting point! I support some older browsers so this is good for me. We could use transform to rotate the arrow as we like it in more modern browsers. HTH

---

```
  <div class="RightArrow">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="point"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- for very short arrows reduce the width of .line --> 

<style> /* style tag added so SO will syntax color please use *.css irl*/
.RightArrow {
   width:90%;
   position: relative;
}

.line {
   margin-top:8px;
   width:97%;
   background:blue;
   height:0.3em;
   float:left;
   position: absolute;
}
.point {    
   width: 0; 
   height: 0; 
   border-top: 10px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
   border-left: 37px solid blue;
   float:right;
}
</style>
```