# How to draw half-opened line in CSS?

Tags: css, responsive-design, line, draw

Right half-opened line segment picture:

[image]

How to draw this line in CSS? With responsive horizontal line part. I found [How can I make a pointy arrow with a div in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816486/how-can-i-make-a-pointy-arrow-with-a-div-in-css) and https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS ,but I don't have skills to concat these.

Comment: i update the arrow fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fqcFp/499/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this with one elements and one pseudo-element `:before` using `Flexbox`

```css
.line {
  width: 150px;
  height: 2px;
  background: black;
  margin: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.line:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but how to reverse this? .line with .line::after doesn't work.

Comment: Please create fiddle and show me what you mean.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/524o575r I need https://yt3.ggpht.com/-3TxDIZx2XJY/VivZFKRVMeI/AAAAAAAAAD4/CDopwio6gK8/w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no/Channel%2BArt%2BTemplate%2B%2528Photoshop%2529.jpg in HTML+CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/524o575r/1/

Comment: Thank you. You're great!