# Drawing an arrow in css

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I need to draw an arrow, preferably using pseudo (:after or :before) elements. it is supposed to look like this: [image]
But it looks like this:
[image]

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="info">
<a href="http://www.bay42.io" class="arrow1"><p>Learn about our technology<span class="arrow-right"></p></span></a></div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow-right:after{
        content: "";
        display:inline-block!important;
            width:0;
            height:0;
            border-left:14px solid #C8A962;
            border-top:14px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a pointy arrow with a div in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816486/how-can-i-make-a-pointy-arrow-with-a-div-in-css)

Comment: You can use the characyere → . See :  https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref you'll find the character entities that you need. for a pseudo, use  content:"\2192"; + font-size to scale it

Comment: CSS is not a drawing tool. You should use an image for this or, even better, learn how to do such simple things with SVG--a proper drawing tool.

Comment: Can't you just use a SVG, which is more useful and easier to work with?

Answer (score 6):

Well of course it looks like that because you use a code just for the `triangle` part of the arrow.

You need to add the other part also. You can do that with the other pseudo-element `before`.

You can change and adjust 'width' 'height' 'color' and so on.

```css
.arrow-right:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 8px solid #C8A962;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
  vertical-align: middle;

}

.arrow-right:before {
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #C8A962;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="info"><a href="http://www.bay42.io" class="arrow1">
    Learn about our technology<span class="arrow-right"></span>
  </a></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like my comment got lost

> You can use the character → . See : https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref you'll find the character entities that you need. for a pseudo, use `content:"\2192"`; + `font-size` to scale it

```css
.arrow1::after {
  content: '\2192';
  /* little make up */
  font-size: 2em;
  /* whatever needed*/
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  /* whatever needed*/
  vertical-align: -0.1em;
  /* whatever needed*/
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float:left;
  clear:both
}

.arrow1:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: '\21fe';
  display:inline-block;
  transform:scale(2,1);
}

.arrow1:nth-child(3)::after {
  content: '\21d2';
  display:inline-block;
  transform:scale(2,0.8);
}
```

```html
<a href=" " class="arrow1">Learn about our technology</a>

<a href=" " class="arrow1">Another one stretched</a>

<a href=" " class="arrow1">or that one can be used and stretched too</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using arrow html code **&#8594** for this purpose

```html
<div class="info">
<a href="http://www.bay42.io" class="arrow1"><p>Learn about our technology</a><span>&#8594;</span><p></p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p {
 position: relative;
 width: max-content;
}

.arrow-right:after {
 top: 50%;
 right: -50px;
 position: absolute;
 content: "";
 display: inline-block !important;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-left: 14px solid black;
 border-top: 14px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 14px solid transparent;
 transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.4);
}

.arrow-right:before {
 content: "";
 width: 25px;
 height: 1px;
 background: black;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: -40px;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Try this. Change the colour to white.